# Windows 7 always boots into Startup Repair

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

A friend's laptop was experiencing extreme difficulties, after trying to the debug the problems the laptop began booting into Startup Repair instead of the OS, even without the installation disk. How can I resolve this?

Also, when I insert the Windows 7 installation disk (Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit, the correct OS for the one currently installed), I don't have the option the upgrade or even "Repair your Computer". It just takes me straight in to install a new copy of Windows by selecting from the list of available partitions. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392
(How to use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows)